# TestNG parallel classes stops working when grouped by instance

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to get TestNG to run classes in parallel - and to show the test result grouped by class.

I have the following testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" >
    <parameter name="api" value="PhantomJS"/>
    <test name="Test PhantomJS" thread-count="8" parallel="classes"  group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.TestOne"/>
            <class name="tests.TestTwo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

What ends up happening is that the classes run sequentially (ignore the method order for now.):

```
TestOne methodOne
TestOne methodThree
TestOne methodTwo
TestTwo methodOne
TestTwo methodThree
TestTwo methodTwo
```

If I remove `group-by-instances="true"` - it runs parallel, but not grouped by class:

```
TestOne
TestOne.methodOne
TestTwo
TestTwo.methodOne
TestTwo.methodThree
TestTwo.methodTwo
TestOne
TestOne.methodThree
TestOne.methodTwo
```

How do I get the classes to be grouped correctly, and also run in parallel?

Comment: you are on which version of testng?

Comment: @anshulGupta testng version 6.10